# Парсинг JSON при помощи JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, парсер, json.net

Имеется вот такое дерево JSON:

```js
{
  "username":"Named",
  "workers": {
    "Named.w1":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"60570","username":"Named.w1"},
    "Named.w2":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"69105","username":"Named.w2"},
    "Named.w3":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"68004","username":"Named.w3"},
    "Named.w4":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"54238","username":"Named.w4"},
    "Named.w5":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"52310","username":"Named.w5"},
    "Named.w6":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"63323","username":"Named.w6"},
    "Named.w7":{"alive":"1","hashrate":"63048","username":"Named.w7"}
  }
}
```

Пробовал создавать классы при помощи [JSON-генератора](http://json2csharp.com/), но классы создаются не правильно. Думаю из-за того что в `username` присутствует точка, и среда ругается на отсутствие класса или пространства имен. Если при создании классов точку удалить - все правильно, но не удается десериализовать в объекты. Да и идея не совсем универсальная, т.к. она будет работать только на определенного пользователя.

Пробовал создать другой вариант:

```
JObject search = JObject.Parse(text);
IList<JToken> results = search["workers"].Children().ToList();
IList<User> Users = new List<User>();
foreach (JToken token in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);
    User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(token.ToString());
    Users.Add(user);
}
```

Ругается:

> Error converting value "Named.w1" to type 'CACoinotronSendMail.User

Сам класс описан вот таким образом:

```
public class User
{
    public string alive { get; set; }
    public string hashrate { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно десериализовать такой JSON, где `username` не является уникальным?

Answer (score 2):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class User {
    public string alive { get; set; }
    public string hashrate { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}

var j = JToken.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\json.txt"));
foreach (var t in j["workers"].Children()) {
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(t.First.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(user.hashrate);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.